# Unfriend multiple friends at once on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey

I'd really like to delete a large number of friends (~400) from my Facebook network and I'd really like to optimize this process.

I found a greasemonkey script that will apparently help here: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/160224

However I'm hesitant to use it since I don't understand the source code (don't know JavaScript) and I have no way of telling weather it is malware.

My questions are:

1. Does someone know how to remove many friends at once from Facebook?
2. Has someone tried this particular Greasemonkey script? did it work?
3. If someone has time, and JavaScript experience, could you tell me if there is anything malicious in the source code?

Comment: Your first question is off-topic for SU (on-topic for webapps.SE though). Also, if you don't trust the stranger who wrote the script, why would you trust another to vet it for you?

Comment: Well, I'd like to think that a crowdsourced opinion is better since I believe most people to be good. Also, they have less incentive because they would not benefit from whatever harm may come my way (such as stealing my information).

Comment: Remember that if you're simply polling for opinion the question is likely to be closed as being "not constructive".

Comment: If you have that many people to remove, how many will be left. Would it be easier to just create a new account?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the developer of that script (Really!  Honestly! **Truuuust** me!), but looking it over, it does not *appear* to be malware.  For instance you see no XHR or `GM_xmlhttpRequest` requests to third-party servers.  It has no *obvious* attempts at hackery.

As for doing what it says it will, It *looks* like it should, and with a nice mechanism to select and confirm those friends to remove.  I have no intention of testing the script.

It's always a good idea to [backup your FB friends](https://www.google.com/search?q=backup%20facebook%20friends), for peace of mind, if nothing else.